# Problems when parsing nested html tags from string

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I have this code that's to parse a string into html and display the text of each element. 
That's working good except when I have nested tags for example `<div><p>Element 1</p><p>Element 2</p></div>`. In this case, the code displays `<p>Element 1</p><p>Element 2</p>`.
How can I do to get each tags one after the other ? (Here I want `Element 1` and then `Element 2`)

Here's the code :

```
let text = new DOMParser().parseFromString(stringHtml, 'text/html');
let textBody = text.body.firstChild;

while (textBody) {
    alert(textBody.innerHTML);
    // other actions on the textBody element
    textBody = textBody.nextSibling;
}
```

Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a recursive function that prints the `textContent` of itself, or of its children, if it has children:

```js
const stringHtml = '<div><p>Element 1</p><p>Element 2</p></div><div><p>Element 3</p><p>Element 4</p></div>';
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(stringHtml, 'text/html');

const showElms = parent => {
  const { children } = parent;
  if (children.length) Array.prototype.forEach.call(children, showElms);
  else console.log(parent.textContent);
}
showElms(doc.body);
```

That's assuming you want to iterate over the *actual elements*. If you want all text nodes instead, then recursively iterate over the `childNodes` instead.

Comment: Thanks for helping me
Is there a way to do that without using any recursive function ?

Comment: Because you want to get all nested elements, a recursive function *is* the best way to accomplish that. There are probably alternatives, but recursion is probably by far the cleanest general method.