# Is it possible to sort bracket pairs or equivalet pairs from the middle to the outside only using a index in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am currently trying to write a templating engine in vanilla javascript. I already filtered the required start and end points for the for loops using regex using the .exec function, thus i have the match itself and the starting index. Now, for the code to 'render' everything properly, the 'pairs' need to be ordered like you would execute them using the bracket rule you use in math.

[Here](https://jsbin.com/mavupezaxo/edit?html,js,console,output) is a demo, where the html contains the data the server would send. It looks like everything is displayed correctly, but a part (compare with template below) is missing. I marked where the sorting should happen with a `// The sorting should happen here` comment. The template is base64 encoded, here is a non-encoded version:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Demo of NSSR</h1>
        <h2>Nested for loop</h2>
        {for _itm in test_arr}
        <h3>For item in array:</h3>
        {for itm in test_arr}
        <p>{itm}</p>
        {-for} {-for}
        <h2>For with two variables</h2>
        <h3>Points:</h3>
        {for x, y in two_dimensional_array}
        <p>Point({x}, {y})</p>
        {-for}
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the full code:

```js
function render_exception(type, description, additional) {
    document.body.innerHTML = `
    <h1>An error occured while rendering the template.</h1>
    <div style="background-color:red;color:white;padding-inline:0.2rem;">
        <h2>${type}</h2>
        <h4>${description}</h4>
    </div> ${additional}
    `;
    return "RenderException";
}

function get_all_regex_matches(regex, str) {
    var res = [];
    var ptrn = RegExp(regex, "mg");
    var match;

    while ((match = ptrn.exec(str)) != null) {
        res.push(match);
    }

    return res;
}

function render_nssr(data, vars, subcall = false) {
    var html = subcall ? data : atob(data);

    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                  For loops                                 */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    while (1) {
        var start_for = get_all_regex_matches(
            /{ ?for [a-zA-Z, _]+ in [a-zA-Z-_]+ ?}/,
            html
        );
        var end_for = get_all_regex_matches(/{ ?-for ?}/, html).reverse();

        console.log({ start_for, end_for, vars });

        if (subcall) {
            console.log(html);
        }

        if (start_for.length !== end_for.length) {
            return render_exception(
                "TemplateSyntaxException",
                `For loops could not be resolved. Got ${start_for.length} start and ${end_for.length} end indicators.`,
                "Non-resolved for loop: " +
                    (start_for.length < end_for.length
                        ? `${end_for[0][0]} at position ${end_for[0]["index"]}`
                        : `${start_for[0][0]} at position ${start_for[0]["index"]}`)
            );
        }

        // The sorting should happen here

        console.log({ start_for, end_for, vars });

        if (start_for.length == 0) {
            break;
        }

        var loop_line = start_for[0][0]
            .replaceAll(/[\{\}]/g, "")
            .replaceAll(/ ?, ?/g, ",")
            .trim()
            .split(/[ ,]/g);

        var start = start_for[0]["index"] + start_for[0][0].length;
        var end = end_for[0]["index"];

        if (!subcall) {
            start_for.forEach(function (it, indx) {
                var s = it["index"] + it[0].length;
                var e = end_for[indx]["index"];
                console.log(s, e, html.substring(s, e));
            });
        }

        var computed_loop_res = "";

        vars[loop_line[loop_line.length - 1]].forEach(function (ele) {
            var var_clone = structuredClone(vars);
            var loop_var_names = loop_line.slice(1, loop_line.length - 2);

            for (var ni = 0; ni < loop_var_names.length; ni++) {
                if (ele.length >= ni + 1) {
                    try {
                        if (loop_var_names.length > 1) {
                            var_clone[loop_var_names[ni]] = ele[ni];
                        } else {
                            var_clone[loop_var_names[ni]] = ele;
                        }
                    } catch (e) {}
                } else {
                    var_clone[loop_var_names[ni]] = undefined;
                }
            }

            console.log(html.substring(start, end));

            computed_loop_res += render_nssr(
                html.substring(start, end),
                var_clone,
                true
            );
        });

        html =
            html.substring(0, start_for[0]["index"]) +
            computed_loop_res +
            html.substring(end_for[0]["index"] + end_for[0][0].length);
    }

    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                              Normal variables                              */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(vars)) {
        html = html.replaceAll(new RegExp(`{ ?${key} ?}`, "mg"), value);
    }

    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                            Returning/Displaying                            */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    if (subcall) {
        return html;
    }

    document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is the previous js code --><script src='nssr.js'></script><script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){render_nssr('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',{"test_arr": ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"], "two_dimensional_array": [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]]})})</script>
```

Here is a python flask server I use for testing and developing:

```py
from flask import Flask, send_file, Response

import os
import base64

app = Flask("NSSR-Example")

def render_nssr_template(file: str, **vars):
    json_var_data = json.dumps(vars)

    with open(os.path.join("./templates", file), "r", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        template_data = base64.b64encode(f.read().encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")

    return Response(
        f"<script src='nssr.js'></script><script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){{render_nssr('{template_data}',{json_var_data})}})</script>"
    )


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_nssr_template(
        "example.html",
        test_arr=["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"],
        two_dimensional_array=[[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]],
    )


@app.route("/<path:path>")
def get_file(path):
    return send_file(path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried to come up with an algorithm, but I couldn't come up with one.
Here is what should happen:

This is a model for our 'bracket pairs' with a sample index:

```
( 1
    ( 2

    ) 3
) 4

( 5


) 6
```

The regex parses them like this:

```js
open = [["(", index: 1], ["(", index: 2], ["(", index: 5]]
close = [[")", index: 3], [")", index: 4], [")", index: 6]]
```

I want these lists sorted in a order, that the first result from 'open' corresponds to the first result from 'open', and inner pairs should be listed in front of there corresponding parents. In my code, these lists are called `start_for` and `end_for`.

The results therefor should look something like this:

```js
open = [["(", index: 2], ["(", index: 1], ["(", index: 5]]
close = [[")", index: 3], [")", index: 4], [")", index: 6]]

or

open = [["(", index: 5], ["(", index: 2], ["(", index: 1]]
close = [[")", index: 6], [")", index: 3], [")", index: 4]]
```

So basically these must be ordered from the inside out, with just the index as 'locational information'.

Is this possible, or has anyone a recommendation on a better approach?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the two arrays (`open`, `close`) to have corresponding values in the same indexes of their respective arrays? That is to say, something [like this](https://i.imgur.com/jd0Qqgn.png)? In the linked image, the indexes for 2 and 3 match, the indexes for 1 and 4 match, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: And your initial intent is to recognize the nesting of the elements within HTML? If so, perhaps you could simplify it all [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51774013) (a DOM parsing solution).

Comment: Do you think this would be easily implementable for a templating engine, especially with the special syntax I used? If yes, this could be a good solution.

Comment: I can't offer anything better than - test it out on a small (but realistic) example, just so you could get a feel for it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try integrating this method into my code.